# How do I create a shared chatter file via API?

Tags: rest-api, chatter, chatter-file

If I call the standard SF API to create a new ContentVersion object and pass the base64-encoded data as the VersionContent (as well as PathOnClient and Title properties) I can create a ContentVersion object which is linked to a ContentDocument which is accessible to all users in the org.

However, I don't want to have to use the base64 data! I saw there's a chatter api endpoint `/services/data/v39.0/connect/files/users/me` and was able to successfully post to this endpoint to create a file but:

1. the file is private
2. the file does not generate a preview

Is there any way to create a chatter file via the chatter api that:

1. creates a file visible to all members of my org
2. generates a preview

?

Comment: So you would rather submit the binary data via a multipart/form-data request rather than Base 64 encoding it into a request?

Comment: it's easier to piggyback on existing tools when uploading multipart/form-data